# How to create a vertical gradient bar with animation in it?

Tags: css, css-animations, gradient

[image]

I want to animate the bar which you can see beside Welcome to Lucknow
As I do not know much about css animation.
Please anybody help.

Comment: How do you want to animate it?

Comment: like a gradient animation with first red and orange color going down then the same colors to up

Comment: @AlonEitan I understand that and have read that at login only but what should I do if I am really in need of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #ffee00, #ff0000, #ff00ff);
  background-size: 200% 200%;

  -webkit-animation: AnimationName 5s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: AnimationName 5s ease infinite;
  animation: AnimationName 5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:50% 00%}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: thank you sir but can you make it in vertical direction please

Comment: Fixed, if you are satisfied you can mark it as correct.